# How do I gracefully respond when Laravel returns 'Missing argument 1 for closure' with non existing resource identifier?

Tags: laravel-4

I'm trying to return a user profile based on username, not profile id.

Decided to user Route / Model Binding.

When I get a valid username it returns the profile,
 but when I get a nonexistent username it returns

"Missing argument 1 for {closure}()"

How do I handle this gracefully?

```
Route::bind('profile',function($value, $route){
    return Profile::where('username', $value)->first();
});

Route::get('profile/{profile}',function($profile){
    if($profile){
        return $profile;
    }
    else{
        return Response::make('empty',400);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least leave a comment why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on another forum:

Set `$profile=false` on second closure.